# What's the equivalent of ruby blocks in java

Tags: java, ruby

Ruby blocks are handy for wrapping some code around some block defined by the caller.

How to do this in Java?

```
def myf(i)
  puts "start"
  yield i
  puts "end"
end

myf(3){ |i| puts i * 10 }
myf(4){ |i| puts i - 10 }

# outputs:
# start
# 30
# end
# start
# -6
# end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to do this in Java?

There is no equivalent to Ruby blocks in Java. Ruby blocks are syntactically lightweight, semantically lightweight, and they are not objects. They are mostly syntactic constructions with some lightweight semantics behind. In this, they are more like an enhanced `for` loop in Java.

The closest equivalent you have in Java, would be a [*functional interface*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) combined with a [*lambda expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27). Something like this, using one of the pre-defined functional interfaces from the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package, namely the interface [`java.util.function.Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

```java
void myf(int i, java.util.function.Consumer<Integer> proc) {
    System.out.println("start");
    proc.accept(i);
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

You use it like this:

```java
myf(3, i -> System.out.println(i * 10));
myf(4, i -> System.out.println(i - 10));
// start
// 30
// end
// start
// -6
// end
```

However, this is *not* equivalent to Ruby's blocks. This is equivalent to Ruby's [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html)s and [*lambda literals*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs), in other words, it is more equivalent to this:

```rb
def myf(i, proc)
  puts "start"
  proc.(i)
  puts "end"
end

myf(3, -> i { puts i * 10 })
myf(4, -> i { puts i - 10 })

# start
# 30
# end
# start
# -6
# end
```

Note that `myf` in your example does not use the result of the block, so modeling it with [`java.util.function.Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) would be incorrect. `Consumer<T>` is the correct interface to use for a "function" (more a procedure, really) that "consumes" its argument but doesn't return anything, whereas `Function<T, R>` is the correct interface to use for a function that takes one argument and returns a result.

Comment: I used `Function` because the OP's Java code was using the result (at variance with their Ruby code, I think, but I don't do Ruby).

Answer (score 2):

Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104313/157247) is correct that [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (combined with functional interfaces) make this possible in Java, but it can be much less complicated than that by using the types in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html). Here's that code using [`Function<T,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html):

`myf`:

```
public static int myf(int i, Function<Integer,Integer> fn) {
    System.out.println("start");
    int retval = fn.apply(i);
    System.out.println(retval);
    System.out.println("end");
    return retval;
}
```

Using it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myf(3, i -> i * 10);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−− lambda expression
    myf(4, i -> i - 10);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−− lambda expression
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/YJYTYF)

I used `Function` because your Java code seemed to show that you wanted a return value. If you don't want a return value, just use [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

Comment: Is it possible to modify to have more arguments? Something like: `int myf(int i, int j, Function<Integer,Integer> fn)` and `int retval = fn.apply(i,j);` ?

Comment: Oh god this works: https://gist.github.com/sidazhou/b7f49fc90819b81b0119e9f00ac0ffe7
  Surely this can't be the right way to do it.

Comment: The right way to do it is to use [`java.util.function.BiFunction<T, U, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

Comment: @SidaZhou - As I said, you use the types (plural) in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html). :-) One of those is `BiFunction<T, U, R>` as Jörg said: a function accepting two arguments (the types of which are the generic paramters `T` and `U`) and returning a value (the type of which is the generic parameter `R`). So `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`.

Comment: Or `BiConsumer<T,U>` if you don't need a return value, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.8, Lambda expression can be used to achieve the desired result:

```
public class Temp {
    interface BlockBody {
        int op(int b);
    }

    public static int myf(int i, Temp.BlockBody blockBody) {
        System.out.println("start");
        int out = blockBody.op(i);
        System.out.println(out);
        System.out.println("end");
        return out;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // block lambda function defined here
        Temp.BlockBody blockBody = (int a) -> {
            int c = a * 10;
            return c;
        };
        int result = Temp.myf(3, blockBody);

        // block body is changed
        Temp.BlockBody blockBody2 = (int a) -> {
            int c = a - 10;
            return c;
        };
        int result2 = Temp.myf(4, blockBody2);
    }
}

// outputs:
// start
// 30
// end
// start
// -6
// end
```

Comment: You can make that a **lot** less complicated by using the types in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: I would really like to know how.